# Autolayout TableView Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I'm having a strange issue with my tableview, debugging the view hierarchy i'm getting this

[image]

I've tried a lot of constraints with no result, how should I setup my tableview to avoid that kind of misplacement ?

Edit

I've a custom cell with an image view, actually set just this 5 constraints

[image]

Top, bottom, leading and trailing values are 0

Comment: what do your current autolayouts look like?

Comment: I once made the mistake that I forgot setting tableview constraints, and the table was partially offscreen.

Comment: @gabbler how did you setup your tableview constraints ?

Comment: No constraints were set, I then set it almost like what you did in your picture, except the first one, which was not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set Your `UITableView` constraint to Leading,Trailing, Top and Bottom. and also for your `UIImageView` set same constraint. so your imageview will show fit to cell as per table width. no need to set `Align Center X` constraint.